# The term 'scaffold-dbcontext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, scaffolding

I am trying to use database-first model to create a `dbContext` and database entities.

When I run this command

```
scaffold-dbcontext "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFramework.sqlserver -outputdir Models
```

I get this error:

> - scaffold-dbcontext "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;In ...
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scaffold-dbcontext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I know how to resolve this if I was using Entity Framework Core but I am using Entity Framework 6.0.0 and all the solutions I have found address the Entity Framework Core version.

Thank you.

I tried to add `EntityFramework.Tools` in the Nuget Package Manager but I could not find it. I also tried to include it in the `.csproj` file but it didn't work. It appears that there is no `EntityFramework.Tools dll`.

Comment: For EF 6 use the built in VS tooling

Comment: @ErikEJ What is "built in VS tooling" ? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Add Entity Data Model Wizard

Answer (score 0):

For EF 6 use the built in VS tooling